# Why are'nt new list items being added displayed on separate lines?

Tags: javascript, html

this is a basic to do list code with only a function to add an item yet in the functionality part, but whenever i add an item they get displayed on the same line, next to each other and also without any bullet points. cant understand why( new to web development)
[image inserted to illustrate](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cdMyb.png)

relevant HTML:

```
<body>
<h1>
    <strong>TO DO LIST</strong>
</h1>
<input type="text" id="newitem" placeholder="enter item name">
<button id="btn" type="button" onclick="add();" >ADD ITEM</button>
<h2>
    undone: <br>click on required items to move them to done list
</h2>
<ul id="dolist">

</ul>
<h2>
    done: <br>click on required items to move them back to undone list
</h2>
<ul id="donelist">


</ul>

<script type="text/javascript" src="jsfunc.js"></script>
</body>
```

`javascript:

```
var dolist=document.getElementById('dolist');
function add()
{
var item=document.createElement("item");
var val=document.getElementById("newitem").value;

var t=document.createTextNode(val);
item.appendChild(t);
dolist.appendChild(item);

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably meant `li` instead of `item`. `item` is not a valid HTML element, whereas `li` indicates a list item - for ordered lists `ol` and unordered lists `ul` alike.

```js
var dolist = document.getElementById('dolist');

function add() {
  var item = document.createElement("li");
  var val = document.getElementById("newitem").value;

  item.textContent = val;
  dolist.appendChild(item);
}
```

```html
<h1>
  <strong>TO DO LIST</strong>
</h1>
<input type="text" id="newitem" placeholder="enter item name">
<button id="btn" type="button" onclick="add();">ADD ITEM</button>

<h2>
  undone: <br>click on required items to move them to done list
</h2>
<ul id="dolist">
</ul>

<h2>
  done: <br>click on required items to move them back to undone list
</h2>
<ul id="donelist">
</ul>
```